# Vertical alignment of enumeration label with enumitem

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumitem

I'm trying to create a few new enumerate-type environments such as `enumerate-alph` to have manual numbering type but also match the label style of my document class. In defining `enumerate-alph`, `enumerate-arabic` and `enumerate-roman`, I'm using essentially the same code, yet the labels are not vertically aligned. How can I fix this behavior?

Below is a MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{enumerate-alph}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[enumerate-alph]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=*,
    label=\normalfont\emph{\alph*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
    ref = \normalfont\emph{\alph*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$}
\newlist{enumerate-arabic}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[enumerate-arabic]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=*,
    label=\normalfont\arabic*$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
    ref = \normalfont\arabic*$\mskip-1mu\big)$}
\newlist{enumerate-roman}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[enumerate-roman]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=*,
    label=\normalfont\emph{\roman*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
    ref = \normalfont\emph{\roman*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate-alph}
    \item Text
\end{enumerate-alph}

\begin{enumerate-arabic}
    \item Text
\end{enumerate-arabic}

\begin{enumerate-roman}
    \item Text
\end{enumerate-roman}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment is quite fine if you remove `leftmargin=*` and `labelsep=*` :

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{enumerate-alph}{enumerate}{10}
    \setlist[enumerate-alph]{%
        label=\normalfont\emph{\alph*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
        ref = \normalfont\emph{\alph*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$}
    \newlist{enumerate-arabic}{enumerate}{10}
    \setlist[enumerate-arabic]{%
        label=\normalfont\arabic*$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
        ref = \normalfont\arabic*$\mskip-1mu\big)$}
    \newlist{enumerate-roman}{enumerate}{10}
    \setlist[enumerate-roman]{%
        label=\normalfont\emph{\roman*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$,
        ref = \normalfont\emph{\roman*}$\mskip-1mu\big)$}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate-alph}
        \item Text
    \end{enumerate-alph}

    \begin{enumerate-arabic}
        \item Text
    \end{enumerate-arabic}

    \begin{enumerate-roman}
        \item Text
    \end{enumerate-roman}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. The removed code is my failed attempt to remove the left indent, do you have some idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Jinwen: If you mean the indentation of the label, you could use `labelwidth=widthof{\textit{a}$\mskip-1mu\big)$}` , or any letter you know you'll use. You also can set `labelindent=0pt`. If you mean yje indentation of the item contents, this is set with `labelsep`.